# Jquery how to change the oder of accordion

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-accordion

I have a Jquery accordion with contents like this

```
<h3>
 <a href="#"> header 1 </a>
</h3>
  contents 1
<h3>
 <a href="#"> header 2 </a>
</h3>

  content 2 

<h3>
 <a href="#"> header 3 </a>
</h3>
```

content 3

When I view this HTML page, the accordion shows the heading as it is. Is there a way I can show header 3 first then header 1 , header 2 etc... Basically, I should be able to specify which header should  be shown first when the HTML is displayed.

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you http://jsfiddle.net/Z5hZJ/1/

```
$('h3 a').click(function(){
    $(this).parents('h3').prependTo('.headers');
});
```

Comment: thanks for the response. I want different headers on top when the page loads, not when we click on a specific header.